# How do i put these letter grades into a new file instead of putting it on the console?

Tags: java, file, file-io

This code creates a file with students and their scores. I have calculated their letter grade but it goes on the console. How can i get their letter grades into a new file? Also how can i print on the console the averages for each test/quiz because right now I have them all in a for loop.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ReadFile {

private Scanner x;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner (new File ("grades.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }}



    public void createFile()throws IOException {


        try{
            File file = new File("grades.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);




        while(s.hasNext()){
        {
            String [] split = s.nextLine().split(", ");

            String fname = split[0];

            Double q1 = Double.parseDouble (split[1]);
            Double q2 = Double.parseDouble (split[2]);
            Double q3 = Double.parseDouble (split[3]);
            Double q4 = Double.parseDouble (split[4]);
            Double proji = Double.parseDouble (split[5]);
            Double projii = Double.parseDouble (split[6]);
            Double projiii = Double.parseDouble (split[7]);

            double studentgrade = (q1 *0.1) + (q2 *0.1) +(q3 *0.1) + (q4 *0.1) +(proji*0.15) + (projii * 0.2) + (projiii *0.25);
            if(studentgrade>90)
                System.out.printf("%s got an A\n", fname);
            else if(studentgrade>80)
                System.out.printf("%s got a B\n", fname);
            else if(studentgrade>70)
                System.out.printf("%s got a C\n", fname);
            else if(studentgrade>60)
                System.out.printf("%s got a D\n", fname);
            else if(studentgrade>50)
                System.out.printf("%s got a F\n", fname);


        }}}catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please read a tutorial on Java IO.

Answer (score 4):

Create a Buffered Writer. Something like this,

```
String fileName = outputName;

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        // create a temporary file

        File outFile = new File(fileName);

        // This will output the full path where the file will be written
        // to...

        String inFile = new File(inFileName).getAbsolutePath();

        File in = new File(inFile);

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputName, true));
        writer.write(DATA THAT YOU WANT TO WRITE(Possibly an Method Argument Value));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            // Close the writer regardless of what happens...
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Your `outputName` is an argument taken by the method (from the code I wrote in one of my programs) that is the name of the file you want to write.

inFileName is the other argument taken and it is the name of the original file you wrote. It will require more work to use this exact code, otherwise,

**The Main Answer: **

Use a `BufferedWriter`!

**EDIT: **

Just as a side note, when you are initiating the `BufferedWriter`, you are giving it two arguments, `outputName` and `true`. The output name is obviously the name that you want to output the file as, and the `true` means that you want to append to the text file (can add to existing data without overwriting the current text file)

Answer (score 1):

If you have this:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");
```

before your loop and then replace all your `System.out.println(...)` statements inside the loop with `writer.println(...)`, closing the PrintWriter after the loop (with `writer.close()`), you will get the output file with the desired text. But do read up properly on Java IO.